# App Crashes When Resumed from minimize After long time

Tags: android

I am working on Taxi Tracking App in which i am tracking stop points for tracking taxi. when user starts app he selects taxi no and start tracking and app goes to minimize and tracking started using service.

when i walk for 1-2 hour and app is in minimize state and when i click on app icon app gives null pointer exception on spinner "on item selected listener" (NULL Pointer Exception).

I am setting adapter of spinner from database (list of taxis).but when i restore app from minimize then why app crashes.

why **onitemselectedlistener** event is called  ??
why it gives null pointer exception in listener because app is in run state already.it was just in background using home intent.

```
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
```

please help me.

Comment: Please post your full stacktrace.

Comment: It seems Android killed your app, and your views loosed their respective initialization...

Comment: I am not able to take stack trace because it does not crash in emulator and device which is connected to system. it crashes when device is not connected to system.